# How to make this work random numbers in C#

Tags: c#

I am having problems with generating random numbers. I don't know how can I writeline it and why it's not working when I add if statement. Thanks for help.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int first= 1;
        int second = 2;
        {
            Random r_first = new System Random();
            r_first = r_first.next(-100, 0);
            Console.WriteLine(first); // I would like to see the result 

            Random r_second = new System Random();
            second = r_second.next(-100, 0);
            Console.WriteLine(second); // I would like to see the result 

            if (first > second)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("first is bigger");

            }

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("first is smaller");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not how random numbers work. Create a *single* `System.Random` and call it's methods multiple times to get multiple random values.

Comment: 1) C# is case sensitive. It is `.Next()` not `.next()` 2) If you use full name you should use as `System.Random()` not `System Random()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have **more than one mistake** in your code.

1. Don't create a new `Random` instance for getting new Random number. Most of the time it will give same value. So you need a single instance of  the `Random` class.
2. The method name is `Next` not `next`
3. Write `System.Random()`, not `System Random()`

   ```
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       int first = 1;
       int second = 2;
       {
           Random randomIns = new System.Random();

           first = randomIns.Next(-100, 0);
           Console.WriteLine(first); // I would like to see the result 
           second = randomIns.Next(-100, 0);
           Console.WriteLine(second); // I would like to see the result 

           if (first > second)
           {
               Console.WriteLine("first is bigger");

           }

           else
           {
               Console.WriteLine("first is smaller");
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: thank you for your help, it's working. I am still beginner in C#. Have a nice day.

Comment: @tydek I am glad to hear it. Don't forget to mark it as answer.You can  Click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem 1:** You are assigning the Random Integer value  to the `Random` class reference variable `r_first`.

Replace This:

```
r_first = r_first.next(-100, 0);
```

With This:

```
first = r_first.Next(-100, 0);
```

**Problem 2:**

if its not a typo you should use `System.Random();` instead of `System Random();`

Answer (score 0):

1) You don't have to make new Random for calling it multiple times.

2) You can't assign value to random method (rng = rng.Next() - you can't do this, you have to define new variable to save result of rng method)

3) Random is part of System namespace so call System.Random() of simply Random()

Try this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int first = 1;
        int second = 2;
        Random rng = new Random();
        first = rng.Next(-100, 0);
        Console.WriteLine(first); // I would like to see the result 

        second = rng.Next(-100, 0);
        Console.WriteLine(second); // I would like to see the result 

        if (first > second)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("first is bigger");

        }

        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("first is smaller");
        }

    }
```